# vs2008 can I get value of line number @ *?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

**Scenario:**

I've recently learned about Mark Russinovich's useful DebugView* utility.
With DebugView, even with vs2008 closed, I can use statements like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("some text =. " + some_variable);
```

I would like to modify the above, at compile time, to include the source code line number:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("nnnn: some text =. " + some_variable);
```

where nnnn represents the source code line number.

AFAIK, to do this, vs2008 would need some form of meta variable like @linenumber for   current compile time source code line number.  i.e., if the Debug.Writeline statement
is on the tenth line, then such a meta-variable would == 10.

Thus, a debug statement such as the rough example above could be used in multiple places and it would be easy to identify the source code location of each debugging statement.

**QUESTION**:  ***are there meta variables that can be referenced at compile time***?

P.S.:  I could not find the answer to this question via Google and also via SO search feature.

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx
  "DebugView for Windows v4.76", Mark Russinovich; October 16, 2008

Comment: we don't do signatures here, or, "Hello", or "Thanks". It's a Q&A site, and we're not having a discussion.

Comment: FWIW, new in c# 5, .NET 4.5:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute.aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute.aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx ... not exactly what i was looking for three years ago; neverheless useful at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

this is the best way I know to get the ACTUAL line CORRECTLY (i.e. it's the right line because it's in-line)

```
Debug.WriteLine(" hi there I am line number [" + (new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true)).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber().ToString()) + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I hope there is a method to obtain this information faster, here's a way you could get the file name and line number using the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class in the System.Diagnostics namespace:

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true));
string fileName = st.GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
string lineNumber = st.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber().ToString();
string fileNameAndLineNbr = fileName + ":" + lineNumber;

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileNameAndLineNbr + ": some text =. " + some_variable);
```